Calculate the previous month and year in SSRS
I need to calculate the previous month in SSRS based off a month parameter. If the user enters June 2024, it will calculate May 2024. The trouble comes when I need to calculate January to December.
=CDate(Format(DateAdd("m",-1,Parameters!Month.Value),"MMM"))


DateAdd should handle that for you. Don't give it a month value. give it a date.  datefromparts(year, Paramateres!Month.Value, 1)

It would be most helpful to exactly what Parameters!Month.Value contains, so we know what we are working with and can suggest a useful answer. Is it a month number? A month name? A "yyyy-mm" year/month combo string? A "month-name year" string combo as suggested by your question? A first-of-the-month date?

Can't convert a month name to a date value with CDate().

Apparently, CDate() is not a valid function in SQLServer.

I am assuming you are passing the whole date in the parameter:
Parameters!Month.Value = 1/1/2024

=MonthName(MONTH(DATEADD("M", -1,Parameters!Month.Value)))

This will give you the value December
